# Why do I get application errors when I stop and restart my mongod service

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid, system-administration

If I cancel and restart my mongodb on the default port, I reconnect fine and there aren't any problems.
When I do so on my `27018` port, it seems to reconnect in my bash window and I get this statement at the end of the restart:

```
initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27018
websvr] web admin interface listening on port 28018
```

but when I run my app I get errors like

```
Operation failed with the following exception: connection closed
```

and

```
Operation failed with the following exception: Broken pipe - send(2)
:10:in `synchronize'
```

Comment: are you saying "when app is configured to use monogdb at default port 27017 it does reconnect on mongodb restart, but not when configured for port 27018"? I don't believe you ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mongoid creates a connection to the MongoDB process and then keeps this around for performance reasons. If the server goes down the connection is broken at the server end and the client can no longer send requests.

In your [Mongoid configuration](http://mongoid.org/docs/installation/configuration.html) you can configure the connection to be retriable, so that failed connections will be retried in the even of failure.

```
max_retries_on_connection_failure [2]
```

The number in square brackets is the number of times to retry (with half second gap between each try) before raising an exception.